# Kubernetes nginx ingress session affinity across ports

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-service

I have a legacy application we've started running in Kubernetes.  The application listens on two different ports, one for the general web page and another for a web service.  In the long run we may try to change some of this but for the moment we're trying to get the legacy application to run as is.  The current configuration has a single service for both ports:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: service
    port: 8081
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8081
```

Then I'm using a single ingress to route traffic to the correct service port based on path:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-hash-by: "$remote_addr"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myapp.test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /app
      - backend:
          serviceName: app
          servicePort: 8081
        path: /service
```

This works great for routing.  Requests coming into the ingress get routed to the correct service port based on path.  However, the problem I have is that for this legacy app to work the requests to both ports 8080 and 8081 need to be routed to the same pod for each client.  You can see I tried adding the upstream-hash-by annotation.  This seemed to ensure that all requests to 8080 from one client went to the same pod and all requests to 8081 from one client went to the same pod but not that those are the same pod for any one client.  When I run with a single pod instance everything is great but when I start spinning up additional pods some clients get /app requests routed to one pod and /service requests to another and in this application that does not currently work.  I have tried other annotations in the ingress including nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie" and nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: "persistent" as well as trying to add sessionAffinity: ClientIP to the service but so far nothing seems to work.  The goal is that all requests to either path get routed to the same pod for any one client.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Session persistence settings will only work if you set the kube proxy settings such that it forwards requests to local pod only and not to random pods across the cluster.

you can do this by setting the service level settings to:

service.spec.externalTrafficPolicy: Local

you can read more here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/

after doing this , you ingress annotations should work. I have tested this with external load balancer only , not with ingress though.

keeping everything else the same and having this service definition should work

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: service
    port: 8081
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8081
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The attribute "externalTrafficPolicy" only applies to services with type LoadBalancer which are used to automatically provision a load balancer in a cloud environment.  I'm not running in a cloud provider, this is a local private Kubernetes cluster using nginx as the ingress.  So if I try to deploy the service with type=LoadBalancer it just sits in a pending state.

Comment: No, i think not. it applies to all service types, try the service defintion i have posted

Comment: I did, it gives the following error: "ExternalTrafficPolicy can only be set on NodePort and LoadBalancer service".  So I was wrong about "only type LoadBalancer" it could be LoadBalancer or NodePort but does not apply to this service which has the default type ClusterIP.

Comment: yes , u need to make it nodeport. it doesnt make any difference

Comment: That seems to have the same behavior as the original configuration. All requests to 8080 go to the same pod and all requests to 8081 go to the same pod but that pod is not the same for any one client. The description of externalTrafficPolicy sounds like it is about getting the client IP to the end pod. I'm trying to get the ingress and the service to tie the two different ports together when choosing a pod. I don't care what the app sees. I've found a few different ways of sticking a client to a pod for a given port but so far no way to stick a client to a pod for all ports in a service.

Comment: i have not tried ingress , i am using nodePort service with traffic policy to local and then sending traffic to nodeport from external loadbalancer. one extra thing im doing in external LB is to discover the extact node/ip on which the pod is actually running ( every 10 sec ). so that my external loadbalancer is only sending traffic to nodes/ports which have that pod. and then the kube proxy on that node is sending it only to local pod due to external traffic policy to local config